# Strange Error in AWS lambda logs for C# function

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I've been having a play about with an Alexa Lambda skill, however i've started to get a unknown response error back from the service, and the following logged in the Lambda log.

> *** Error in `/var/runtime/awslambda': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007f5f640e4a00 ***

After that error there's a (very) long list of other similar errors.

I've no idea what this means. It seems to be happening when i'm trying to get some data out of a Mysql database. However, i am querying the database at another Intent on the application and that works fine, i've also got local unit tests running that work ok and the sql i'm passing is bringing back data.

This is the method in question:

```html
public userInfo GetJiraCompanyForUser(string alexaUser)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection db = GetConnection())
            {
                db.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE AlexaUser = '{alexaUser}' LIMIT 1", db);
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        return new userInfo
                        {
                            ID = reader.GetInt32("ID"),
                            AlexaUser = reader.GetString("AlexaUser"),
                            Prop1 = reader.GetString("Field1").Trim(),
                            Prop2 = reader.GetString("Field2").Trim(),
                            Prop3 =  reader.GetString("Field3").Trim()
                        };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new userInfo { ID = -1 };    //nothing so send a minus back as the id
                    }                    
                }
            }            
        }
```

Any ideas what might be going on?